# Find the index of a value inside the node in an xml using xslt1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Sample XML:

```
<root>
    <data>
        <row>
            <tn>abc</tn>
        </row>
        <row>
            <tn>def</tn>
        </row>
        <row>
            <tn>gef</tn>
        </row>
    </data>
</root>
```

How can I find the position of the value "def'' inside the node tn?
  I have to find the position using xslt1.0
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. The position of the text node "def'' within its parent `tn` element is 1. Perhaps you should explain your real purpose here.

Comment: Do you mean "which row within `data` contains the "`def`"?  or "at what position within the `tn` element does the string `def` begin?  What position do you expect to get back on your sample data?  What answer would you expect for the value "ef"?  And ... what have you tried?